# ¿Cómo eliminar caracteres de un string?

Tags: vb.net, string, regex

Soy nuevo en Visual Basic .NET necesito saber que código podría usar
para eliminar de un `textbox` caracteres específicos que tengo encerrados entre caracteres especiales.

Ejemplo:

`$% esto es un comentario %$`

Código

---

```
'Eliminar Espacios
        Dim Borrar As String = Trim(TextBox1.Text)
        While Borrar.Contains(" ")
            Borrar = Borrar.Replace(" ", "")
        End While



        'Eliminar saltos de linea
        While Borrar.Contains(vbCrLf)
            Borrar = Borrar.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
        End While



        Lexico.Show()

        'Eliminar comentarios

        Dim pattern As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape("$") & "%.+%" & System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape("$")
        Dim rgx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern)
        Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(TextBox1.Text, "")

        Lexico.TextBox3.Text = result
```

Answer (score 1):

Con expresiones regulares podrías conseguir el patron de búsqueda para remplazar

```
Dim texto As String = "texto_1 $% esto es un comentario %$ texto_2 $% otro comentario %$ texto_3"

Dim regex As new Regex("\$%.*?%\$")
Dim result As String = regex.Replace(texto, "")
```

Comment: Disculpa mi poco conocimiento, no se si tendria que hacer un for para que haga un recorrido por toda la cadena para que almacene todo lo que se escribio en el textbox y asi elimine los comentarios.

Comment: En principio una cadena es un texto simple, salvo que ese textbox sea multiline, pero en principio si usas TextBox1.Text el texto es una simple cadena a la cual el aplicas las expresion regular

Comment: Si, es multiline lo utilizo como un editor de texto.

Comment: Pero es un textbox o un RichTextBox ? si es un textbox podrias ver si usando el .Text toma todo el texto escrito o sino podrias hacer un for con la propiedad Lines  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: es un textbox, si lo toma multilines sin utilizar esa propiedad. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Function QuitarCaracteres(sInput As String) As String
Dim sSpecChar As String
Dim i As Long
Dim letra As String
sSpecChar = ""
Dim Cont As Integer
For i = 1 To Len(sInput)
sInput = Replace$(sInput, Mid$(sSpecChar, i, 1), "")
Cont = Cont + 1
If (Mid$(sInput, i, 1) = ".") Then
Exit For
Else
letra = Mid$(sInput, 1, Cont)
End If
Next
QuitarCaracteres = letra

End Function

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, recuerda que es importante agregar una explicación del código, ¿Cómo ayudaría a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta?, revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar [expresiones regulares](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(v=vs.110).aspx). Ejemplo

```
Dim pattern As String = Regex.Escape("$") & "%.+%" & Regex.Escape("$")
Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
Borrar = rgx.Replace(Borrar, "") 
Lexico.TextBox3.Text = Borrar
```

Tengo que usar [`Regex.Escape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) debido a que el caracter `$` tiene un significado especial dentro de una expresión regular. Por eso debe usarse una secuencia de escape.

Comment: Disculpa mi poco conocimiento, no se si tendria que hacer un for para que haga un recorrido por toda la cadena para que almacene todo lo que se escribio en el textbox y asi elimine los comentarios.

Comment: @Jose95Madrid: no necesitas ningun `for`. Solo usa la propiedad `textboc.Text` en lugar de  `input` en `rgx.Replace(input, "")`

Comment: Gracias entiendo lo que me dices, si funciona pero creo que no me exprese correctamente el programa hace varias cosas una de ellas es eliminar los espacios que hay entre las palabras que se escriben ejemplo : hola como estas. escribes eso y luego en otro textbox te sale eso mismo pero sin espacios asi holacomoestas. entonces utilice ese codigo que me diste y ahora quita los comentarios pero ahora no hace lo otro. no se si es porque me falta un for. y disculpa.

Comment: Tenes que asignar `result` al otro textbox. Podriamos ayudar mejor si mostras tu codigo para saber que te falta.

Comment: puse el codigo.

Comment: Edite mi codigo. Tene en cuenta que el `Replace` actua sobre todo el string, no es necesario hace un while

Comment: Listo ya me funciono, gracias brother